# What happens when the label's dimension is different from neural network's output layer's dimension in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

It makes intuitive sense to me that the label's dimension should be the same as the neural network's last layer's dimension. However, with some experiments using PyTorch, it turns out that it somehow works.

Code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

X = torch.tensor([[1],[2],[3],[4]], dtype=torch.float32) # training input
Y = torch.tensor([[2],[4],[6],[8]], dtype=torch.float32) # training label

model = nn.Linear(1,3)
learning_rate = 0.01
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

for epoch in range(10):
    y_pred model(X)
    loss = nn.MSELoss(Y, y_pred)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    optimizer.step()
```

In the above code,  `model = nn.Linear(1,3)` is used instead of `model = nn.Linear(1,1)`. As a result, while Y.shape is (4,1), y_pred.shape is (4,3).

The code works with a warning saying that "Using a target size that is different to the input size will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. "

I got the following output when I executed `model(torch.tensor([10], dtype=torch.float32))`:

`tensor([20.0089, 19.6121, 19.1967], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)`

All three outputs seems correct to me. But how is the loss calculated if the sizes of the data are different?

Should we in any case use a target size that is different to the input size? Is there a benefit for this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with `batch_size=4`, you are using a target with `1` component vs `3` for your predicted tensor. You don't actually see the intermediate results when computing the loss with [`nn.MSELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MSELoss.html), using the `reduction='none'` option will allow you to do so:

```
>>> criterion = nn.MSELoss(reduction='none')
>>> y = torch.rand(2,1)
>>> y_hat = torch.rand(2,3)
>>> criterion(y_hat, y).shape
(2, 3)
```

Considering this, you can conclude that the target `y`, being too small, has been broadcasted to the predicted tensor `y_hat`. Essentially, in your example, you will get the same result (without the warning) as:

```
>>> y_repeat = y.repeat(1, 3)
>>> criterion(y_hat, y_repeat)
```

This means that, for each batch, you are L2-optimizing all its components against a single value: `MSE(y_hat[0,0], y[0])`, `MSE(y_hat[0,1], y[0])`, and `MSE(y_hat[0,2], y[0])`, same goes for `y[1]` and `y[2]`.

The warning is there to make sure you're conscious of this broadcast operation. Maybe this is what you're looking to do, in this case, you should broadcast the target tensor yourself. Otherwise, it won't make sense to do so.

Comment: I see now, thanks! The code I'm reading is to predict a numeric value based on some features, so is there an advantage of this broadcasting technique?

Comment: If you want to predict a single numeric value, you may need to use a single neuron on your linear layer such that it outputs a single value. In your case `(bs, 1)`.